# Optimize Simple SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a simple select statement:

```
SELECT id1, id2, id3 FROM Table1
```

Table1 contains around 400,000 records.

Currently, this statement takes 5 seconds to execute.

Is it possible to optimize this (without reducing the number of records returned)?

Comment: If you're routinely querying for 400k rows with no filtering to the point that you are concerned with optimizing it, you have a design problem in your application that you should be addressing.

Comment: @SeanBright agreed. This statement won't actually be applied in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an index with all three fields in it and that will cause SQL to read from the index page. This is also known as a covered index. One thing to remember though is that adding the index can slow down write times because the index has to be rebuilt during a write.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_CoveredIndex ON Table1 (id1, id2, id3)
```

However, with only 400K rows, I would say that's probably not an issue.

Comment: +1 Assuming of course that there are more fields in the table than the three selected fields, otherwise an index won't make much difference.

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the speed. I used your above syntax to create the indexes. @Guffa these are the only fields in the table. EDIT looks like it's moody - now it's playing between 3 and 4 :P

Comment: @Rivka: is this "server" your laptop or development box?

Comment: @Mike using my dev machine but connected to an instance (I think) of the live server.

Comment: @Rivka: as you can see, adding the index shaved off 30% to 40% of the query time. Now it feels like you're dealing with a lack of resources on the "server".

Answer (score 1):

No, your query results in a simple table scan. As long as you have no `where` or `order` statement, it is the best you can do.

The question is, why you select all rows without a filter ? If you filter inside your application you doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It's not properly optimization, but you should try using `(nolock)` after the table name, so you won't lock the table during those 5 seconds, allowing other people to use it also...

This is optimization only if you're trying to access the table from multiple places at the same time, so you don't need to wait one end its use of the table to start the other, doing them all at once.

```
SELECT id1, id2, id3 FROM Table1 (nolock)
```

PS: This is SQL Server sintax... don't know about other SGBDs, but pretty sure there are similars... but since your question is about SQL Server, its ok I guess! :)